# Example of a *real* condition in the past

Tags: conditional-constructions

Consider the following *hypothetical* example. A friend of mine named Alex passed away last year. I've found a notebook in his room with pictures of lions. This suggests that he was likely interested in lions. This observation makes me think he may have been interested in tigers too -- because lions and tigers share a lot of similarities.

Can I use the following sentence to describe my opinion -- including the possibly **real** condition that Alex may have been interested in lions; or it will be confused by the second/mixed conditional structure where we talk about **unreal** conditions.

> If Alex was interested in lions, he may have been interested in tigers too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence is fine and sounds natural. Both clauses describe situations that could be real or not, and the past tense* indicates that both "actions" took place in the past (because Alex is no longer alive). Searching in Google Books produced several examples of similar sentences, such as this one (from [Paul Lee's "The Titanic and the Indifferent Stranger"](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Titanic_and_the_Indifferent_Stranger/PnlGDHNSCmoC), pg. 200):

> If Rostron's course was correct, then he may have been to the east of where he thought he was, perhaps caught in the North Atlantic Drift.

And this one (from [William C. Davis's "Inventing Loreta Velasquez"](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Inventing_Loreta_Velasquez/JlAEDQAAQBAJ), pg. 58):

> If the belt was designed for carrying documents, then she may have been in the vicinity of fact.

*The main clause isn't really in the "past tense". It includes a modal verb with the perfect aspect.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for your great help!

Comment: I wonder how you found the above helpful examples from Google books. Did you use any specific technique?

Comment: @Jeff I searched for "then he may have been", "then she might have been", etc.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!!